# angular material 2 checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

Trying to add md-checkbox in a md-cell, so a select all at the top and individual checkbox in each row.  Nothing is currently showing up, when I check source it shows the md-checkbox, but just displays the display value.  Please help.

I used the example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) for Select All

And here is my code:

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectAllChecked" (indeterminate)="selectAllIndeterminate" (click)="selectAllClicked()" ngDefaultControl>
        <span *ngIf="selectAllChecked">Un-</span>Select All
</md-checkbox>
```

selectAllChecked and selectAllIndeterminate are Booleans defaulting to false and the checkbox is still not displaying.  It exists in the html, but just showing the display value.

Comment: The example is for angularjs version, but you are using *ngIf syntax. Which version is the correct one?

Comment: Updated with the correct example but still having the same issue.  Without the ngDefaultControl I was getting console errors, not sure if that value has something to do with them not displaying.

Comment: Select all is in the cell or the header?

Comment: Could you provide a plunker (even not working)?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the import in app.module.ts in the imports section of @NgModule.